# org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 404. Appium error

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testing, automated-tests, appium, appium-android

Here is my config class:

```
public AppiumDriver initializeAndroidDriver() throws MalformedURLException {
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        caps.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2");
        caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "12.0");
        caps.setCapability("deviceName", "e590b90f");
        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
        return driver;
    }
```

My appium version is 2.4.1, and driver is `-- appium-uiautomator2-driver@2.45.1. I've tried stopping and starting appium server, tried with URL  http://192.168.*.*:4723/wd/hub also. Also tried with adding or changing desired capabilities. But every time I'm facing same error:

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 404. Message: The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource

I've tried with other stack overflow solution and also with chatgpt. I'm using Intellij idea and java testng for my mobile app automation project. Tried by turning off firewall. Also all my capabilities are correct, I've checked them with appium desktop. So now, can anyone help me out please?

Comment: Are you also adding app path?

Comment: @Dhamo, No I'm not. The app is already installed in my device. I tried adding appPackage and appActivity. The result is same

Answer (score 0):

```
driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub")
```

Pass like this and try to run it and see

Comment: driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub")